# Checking if user exists and then check for password using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to check if a users exists using PDO and after that if the password is correct, is there a way to make this work? Or do I need 2 queries?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = :username AND password = :password";

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && count($result["name"]) < 1) { ?>
    <div class="sticky-top alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?= $username ?> could not be found. </div>    
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: __never__ store plain passwords in your database use password_hash and password_verify

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Your query will return results only if BOTH conditions match, so if you are saying you want to detect that the user doesn't exist, and treat as a separate case that their password is wrong, then you do need two queries. But for security reasons please DO NOT do this! That lets potential attackers know that they have half the pieces needed to hack you if they can find out is a user is valid without knowing their password.

Comment: I am not soring plain passwords in the database, I was just wondering if it is possible to check if a user exists and then checking if the password is correct using only one query

Comment: It is possible, yes. Query by the given email/username, then compare the hashed password from db via `password_verify()`

Comment: Why do you need to do both checks in a database? Simply use a query which matches only the username a check if the password matches in PHP.